# Word VBA ADO connection to Excel file with cells containing more than 255 characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I currently use the following ADODB connection string to retrieve data from an Excel workbook (the oConnection has been declared as a new ADODB.Connection and the oRecordSet as a new ADODB.RecordSet):

```
With oConnection
   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Myfile.xlsx;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"""
   .Open
   Set oRecordSet = .Execute(mySqlStatement)
End With
```

I add the record set to an array and everything seems to be working fine. However if a cell in the Excel sheet contains more than 255 characters the text is being truncated/the characters above 255 are being cut off.

The entire function that I use for connecting to the Excel file is the following:

```
Public Function RecordSet2Matrix(mSqlStatement As String) As Variant
    Dim oSettingsFolder  As String
    Dim oSettingsFile    As String
    Dim oConnection      As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRecordSet       As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oRecordArray     As Variant
    Dim oTempArray       As Variant
    Dim x                As Long
    Dim y                As Long
    Dim xUpper           As Long
    Dim yUpper           As Long

    'Error handling
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    'Get location and settings file
    oSettingsFolder = GetFolder(xFolderEnum.FolderOther)
    oSettingsFile = xSettingsFile
    oTempArray = Array()

    'Check if settings file exists
    If Len(Dir(oSettingsFolder & oSettingsFile)) = 0 Then
        RecordSet2Matrix = oTempArray
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Create connection to settings file
    With oConnection
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & oSettingsFolder & oSettingsFile & _
                            ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"""
        .Open
        Set oRecordSet = .Execute(mSqlStatement)
    End With

    'Read the settings file and add data to an array
    If oRecordSet.EOF Then
        oTempArray = Array()
    Else
        oRecordArray = oRecordSet.GetRows

        xUpper = UBound(oRecordArray, 2)
        yUpper = UBound(oRecordArray, 1)

        'Resize array to fit all records
        ReDim oTempArray(xUpper, yUpper)
        For x = 0 To xUpper
            For y = 0 To yUpper
                oTempArray(x, y) = oRecordArray(y, x)
            Next y
        Next x
    End If

    'Close connection to file
    If CBool(oRecordSet.State And adStateOpen) Then
        oRecordSet.Close
    End If

    'Return record set
    RecordSet2Matrix = oTempArray

errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ShowErrorMessage Err.Number, Err.Description, "modADO.RecordSet2Matrix"
        Set oRecordSet = Nothing
        RecordSet2Matrix = oTempArray
    End If

cleanUp:
    Set oRecordSet = Nothing
    Set oTempArray = Nothing
End Function
```

Then I run the actual SELECT statement to get the data from Excel:

```
Public Function GetFirmDetails(mFirmName As String) As xIniDataRecord
    Dim oSqlStatement  As String
    Dim oDataArray     As Variant
    Dim oReturnRec     As xIniDataRecord

    'Error handling
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    'SQL query for retrieving office details
    oSqlStatement = "SELECT [FirmDisplayName], [FirmPrintName], [FirmInfoA]" & _
                    "FROM   [Firms$] " & _
                    "WHERE  [FirmDisplayName] = '" & mFirmName & "';"

    'Return query to array
    oDataArray = RecordSet2Matrix(oSqlStatement)

    'Exit function if array is empty
    If UBound(oDataArray) < 0 Then
        GetFirmDetails = oReturnRec
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Return array data to return record
    With oReturnRec
        .FirmDisplayName = oDataArray(0, 0)
        .FirmName = oDataArray(0, 1)
        .FirmInfoA = oDataArray(0, 2)
    End With

    'Return data record
    GetFirmDetails = oReturnRec

errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ShowErrorMessage Err.Number, Err.Description, "modADO.GetFirmDetails"
        GetFirmDetails = oReturnRec
    End If

cleanUp:
    Set oDataArray = Nothing
End Function
```

I have been looking into other questions similar to mine but not really found the solution.

Does anybody know how to avoid the 255 character limitation?

NB! I am running Excel 2007.

Comment: do you mean that your `mySqlStatement` is longer than 255 characters but the `.Execute()` method only uses the first 255 characters?

Comment: It means that in my Excel file I have cells containing more than 255 characters. But for some reason it is only the first 255 characters of each cell that is returned.

Comment: I am not sure I have got enough information to reproduce this problem... What is your SQL statement that youre executing? How are you copying data from your recordset to sheet? Can you provide samples of data your working with?

Comment: I have added the functions that I use to extract from Excel. Basically the Excel file contains one worksheet named "Firms" which then has three columns named FirmDisplayName, FirmPrintName and FirmInfoA.

Answer (score 2):

From tests here, I believe you are encountering the (well-known) problem described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189897/EN-US) (although it talks about ODBC, the problem is much the same in OLEDB). The problem is that the OLE provider wants to assign a specific data type to each column in the worksheet. Then it converts any cells in the column that do not have that format into the assigned format.

By default, it uses the first 8 rows of each column to decide the format. For columns that contain only strings, if the first 8 cells in the column contain strings of <255 (or <=255, can't remember) characters, the provider will truncate any cells with > or >=255. If you have even one cell in the first 8 with >255, the provider will not truncate any of the rows.

The problem with this is of course that it can appear completely arbitrary - one day you have a worksheet with a cell with 255 characters in the first 8 rows, and everything works fine. Then you modify that data and the system goes wrong.

It is not actually completely non-trivial to modify this behaviour. You can set the "TypeGuessRows" value in the registry to be higher, or set it to 0, in which case in theory it will check all rows.

But that will affect everything else that uses the Jet/ACE provider to get data from Excel. Setting the value to 0 may mean that the check takes a long time, and as far as I can remember, the check is only applied to the first 16K (or perhaps 32K or 64K) rows even in recent versions of Excel where the row count can in theory be higher.

To avoid modifying the behaviour of everything else, you can create your own set of Jet/ACE parameters in a private area of the registry, and point to that in the connection string.

A simpler alternative may be to accept that you always have one dummy row at the beginning of your data with texts over 255 characters long in the columns that need them. Personally, that's probably the route I would take.

Otherwise, as long as it makes sense to set the TypeGuessRows to 0 in your situation, and you are allowed to modify the registry, that may be an option for you. For example if you put the values here (you may also need to modify something called "ImportMixedTypes":

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\sample\v1.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\sample\v1.0\Engines\Excel\ImportMixedTypes
```

Then you will need this in your connection string:

```
Jet OLE DB:Registry Path="SOFTWARE\sample\v1.0"
```

A set of suitable registry entries that you can import look like:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\sample]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\sample\v1.0]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\sample\v1.0\Engines]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\sample\v1.0\Engines\Excel]
"ImportMixedTypes"="Text"
"TypeGuessRows"=dword:00000000
```

You could use that approach , but set

```
"TypeGuessRows"=dword:00000001
```

for the case where you have one dummy row, just to ensure that all the types are assigned to be as specified in that row. But I think it would probably be enough in most cases just to add the row.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. However in cell G2 (row 2, column 7) I have added text that is more than 255 characters long. But still I only get the first 255 characters. Any ideas without changing the registry settings?

Comment: (1) you have to save the XL file after changing the value (2) Is the value of TypeGuessRows either absent or set to 8 in the registry on your test system? (3) I have put a small XL test file temporarily at https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuyfc2ehwx18go3/firmdata.xlsx - if you run your code against that and look up "firmi", then delete one character from C7, save and try again, you may see the problem I describe. Always possible that there is a further problem! Other than "add a row at the beginning,", "automate Excel," or "get your data from the XML in the .docx", registry modification needed IMO.

Comment: I have tried changing the TypeGuessRows to 0 but that does not help.

Comment: Well, it is probably a different problem from the one that I mention. But did you try the test file that I posted?